# Import HDFS data using Vaex

Tags: python, hdfs, bigdata, extract, vaex

So im looking for alternatives to access huge volume of data from HDFS beside spark and i found vaex. Is there anyway to directly access data from HDFS using vaex? can i have some example line that you guys found? Thanks